# How to filter entities using queries in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, odata, filtering

I need to create functionality that would allow users to filter entities using literal queries (i.e. `age gt 20 and name eq 'john'`). Is there a provided functionality to do this in C#/Asp.Net MVC or do I have to parse this query by myself?

I found that OData implies having exactly such functionality ([OData Filter Expressions MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169248(v=nav.90).aspx)). However, I'm not familiar with it so I don't know how to implement such behavior in my project.

I need something like this:

```
var list = new List<Person>
{ 
  new Person { Name = "John", Age = 30 },
  new Person { Name = "Hanna", Age = 25 },
  new Person { Name = "John", Age = 15 }
 };

string query = "age gt 20 and name eq /'John/'";
IEnumerable<Person> result = list.FilterByExpression(query); 
// returns list with John aged 30
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a package on Nuget called [`Linq2Rest`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Linq2Rest/), which contains an extension method for `IEnumerable` called `Filter`. You can pass the string of the filter you need to make the filter happen. Internally, it will be converted into a `Expression Tree` and will be used with the ienumerable extension methods existent.

For sample:

```
var filteredSource = source.Filter(Request.Params);
```

See this article [`Creating a .Net queryable client for ASP.Net Web API oData services`](http://blog.petegoo.com/2012/03/11/creating-a-net-queryable-client-for-asp-net-web-api-odata-services/) about how to deal with this type of problem using libraries `JSON.Net` and `Linq2Rest` to solve this problem.